# Google App Script function forwardEmailAsAttachment

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am spinning around regarding script in google app script to do next:

1. In gmail, user get new option (button) forward email as attachment for check
2. Gmail/script forward email as attachment to report@domain.com

Execution and deploy pass fine, but script do not work :/

```
function createReportButton() {
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  var action = CardService.newAction()
    .setFunctionName('forwardAsAttachment');
    
  card.setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader()
    .setTitle('Report')
  );

  card.addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
    .addWidget(CardService.newTextButton()
      .setText('Forward as Attachment')
      .setOnClickAction(action)
    )
  );

  return card.build();
}

function forwardAsAttachment(e) {
  var messageId = e.gmail.messageId;
  var draftBody = 'Attached email: ' + messageId + '\n\n';
  
  var attachments = [{
    fileName: 'email.eml',
    mimeType: 'message/rfc822',
    content: GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId).getBody()
  }];

  GmailApp.createDraft('report@domain.com', 'Forwarded Email', '', {
    attachments: attachments,
    body: draftBody
  });
}
```